# Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 installation fails when done from ms store

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-apps

Update: please delete as this is not the right place for this question. Sorry!

I have a wierd problem with my Windows 10 Pro setup. I want to install Ubuntu bash from the Microsoft store but whenever I click on get/install in the store nothing happens. Working message briefly appears and the store windows kind of reloads and the button goes back to get/install. Any ideas? I tried resetting the store cache and enabling Linux Subsystem through power shell all without luck.

Comment: This question belongs to another sister site of SE network.

Comment: I tried searching for a more relevant page but couldn't find one for windows. Any more specific clues?

Comment: What I am saying is that this question does not belong here. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You **will** definitely get help if you post your question [here](https://superuser.com). It is another site under the Stack Exchange network. Stack Overflow is dedicated to coding. Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know superuser would be better. I will delete the question and post it there. Thanks for your help.